# C++ class extension trouble

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance

I am learning C++ and to do so, I'm implementing some common data structures.

I started implementing a Binary Search Tree and it went all right, so now I'm implementing a Red Black Tree because I want to work through extending the BST Nodes into RBT Nodes (by just adding a bool color to them), and here is when my problems come.

This is my Node definition:

```
// NODE (key, value) //
class Node {

public:
    int key;
    int value; // value is integer for simplicity
    Node *parent;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;

    Node();
    Node(int key, int value);

    Node *grandparent();
    Node *uncle();

};
```

And then I have my RedBlackNode:

```
// RED BLACK NODE (node with color) //
class RedBlackNode : public Node {

public:
    int key;
    int value;

    RedBlackNode *parent;
    RedBlackNode *left;
    RedBlackNode *right;

    bool color;

    RedBlackNode();
    RedBlackNode(int key, int value);

    RedBlackNode *grandparent();
    RedBlackNode *uncle();

};
```

That looks exactly the same, except for the color, and because grandparent() and uncle() return a RedBlackNode and not a Node.

The same happens with my BinarySearchTree methods Insert(key, value) and Search(key), and I would like to know if I have to rewrite all the methods only because of that.

I've been thinking also in using templates, but that doesn't make sense to me, because a BST will only be formed by Nodes, and a RBT will be formed by colored Nodes.

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: You might want to read more about *virtual functions*, and I doubt you even need to do that. Remember that inheritance is a "is a" relationship. `RedBlackNode` *is a* `Node`. The only place where you need to use the color is when inserting nodes into the tree or when rebalancing the tree, and then you can use a *downcast* to cast from `Node*` to `RedBlackNode*`. In short, just the `color` member is needed in the `RedBlackNode` class.

Comment: Also, instead of using a `class` and declare all members `public`, why not use a `struct` where members are `public` by default?

Comment: You're possibly violating the LSP if you derive `RedBlackNode` from `Node` and "reuse" the data members: For `Node`, the pointers can point to *any* class derived from `Node`, but for `RedBlackNode`, they must point to classes derived from `RedBlackNode` (logically). A function `void foo(Node* n) { n.left = new Node(); }` breaks a RBNode when called: `RedBlackNode rbn = {...}; foo(rbn);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @JoachimPileborg.

I'm using a class because I will want to make all the properties private with getters and setters in the "near" future.

I don't really understand what you said about downcasting Node* -> RedBlackNode*. Could you give me an example on the method

Node* Search(int key); // BST

vs

RedBlackNode* Search(int key); // RBT

Comment: Example of downcast: `Node* node = new RedBlackNode(...); static_cast<RedBlackNode*>(node)->color = false;` The `static_cast` expression is the *downcast*. Try searching for the term.

Comment: There is no need to downcast.  (IMHO)  Simply create and use a getter method which you are contemplating anyway.  Add the getter method in pure virtual form to the base class (Node) (since base class does not have a color), and implement the getter method along with your color data to your derived class (RedBlackNode).  If you wish to avoid the pure-virtual getColor(), implement a Node::getColor() to return some color not red or black (neutral?).